# How to start tdding with ruby and wrong?

Tags: ruby, tdd

I know how to do TDD in other languages, but I'm new to both ruby and wrong. I'm struggling a bit with the fundamentals of how to setup a (toy) project. I want to write a method which computes the factorial (`n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * n`). I have created the file `test/factorial_test.rb`, which so far contains

```
require 'wrong'
include Wrong
```

How do I proceed from here? Do I write my assertions in the global scope of the file

```
assert { factorial(1) == 1 }
assert { factorial(2) == 2 }
#...
```

(which feels a bit weird)? Or should I follow some (which?) convention and wrap each test in its own method

```
def one_factorial_should_be_one
  assert { factorial(1) == 1 }
end
```

I'm a bit lost with the fundamentals here, so any answer on what is considered best-practice here is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wrong](http://rubydoc.info/gems/wrong/0.6.1/frames) merely provides a couple (admittedly smart) assertion methods. You still need a framework to automate running the tests, e.g. [minitest](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest).

Answer (score 1):

You can start with `minitest` testing framework that included with standard library. it is more productive and simple then using `assert` directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several testing frameworks available in Ruby

- Test::Unit
- minitest
- rspec
- shoulda - similar to rspec
- cucumber - a BDD testing framework

The basic Ruby testing framework is Test::Unit. A simple example looks as follows:

```
require 'test/unit'
class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_equality
    assert_equal(1,1)
  end
end
```

Recently Minitest was incorporated into Ruby standard library, so if you wish to use this library you don't have to install anything. A simple minitest spec looks as follows:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
describe Factorial do
  it "should provide factorial of 1 as 1" do
    factorial(1).must_equal 1
  end
end
```